# How can I define new relation types in Doccano?

Tags: gui, annotations, doccano

I use [Doccano](https://github.com/doccano/doccano) to do some text annotation. I want to define new relation types in Doccano.

When I click on "Relation" in the left menu:

[image]

I get a 404 error:

[image]

How can I define new relation types in Doccano?

---

My environment:

- doccano==1.8.4
- Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-1039-aws x86_64)
- Python Version Used: Python 3.10.9 (main, Mar  1 2023, 18:23:06) [GCC 11.2.0] on linux

---

To install Doccano, I used:

```
# create conda env and install doccano
conda create -n doccanopy310 python=3.10 anaconda
conda activate doccanopy310
pip install doccano
```

To launch Doccano,  I followed the [official documentation](https://doccano.github.io/doccano/install_and_upgrade_doccano/#install-with-pip). I ran:

```
# Initialize database. First time only.
doccano init
# Create a super user. First time only.
doccano createuser --username admin --password pass
# Start a web server.
doccano webserver --port 8000
```

And from ran another terminal:

```
# Start the task queue to handle file upload/download.
doccano task
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on "Labels" in the left menu, then "Relation":

[image]

It is working there.

(Thanks Mengjiao Zhang for showing me that solution)